# variable "a" is not recognised when contained within the data attribute of the div tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html

in asp is there anything wrong with doing the following:

```
<div id="someid" class="randomClass" data-*="<% a.AnimalId %>"><%: a.AnimalName %></div>
```

because visual studio complains that the type or namespsace could not be found, specifically on the 'a' with in the data attribute with in the div tag, a.AnimalName didn't give any errors...

Would be grateful for some insight

Comment: "data-*"??? (4 to go...)

Comment: @Adriano I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt here. Look at the rest of the attributes, "someid", "randomClass". It's clearly example code.

Comment: @Curt, you're right! I stopped to read even before missing semicolon. My +1

Comment: @Adriano it is my code, copied and pasted and then I put someid and randomclass in there ... not example code at all...thanks **EDIT** sorry I am new to asp...just started it a few minutes ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a colon. Try:

```
<div id="someid" class="randomClass" data-*="<%: a.AnimalId %>"><%: a.AnimalName %></div>
```

Comment: oh my gosh really! that was all :\ And I wanted to stick to non-mvc/asp/c# questions :| thank you so much! probably going to be the easiest question you answer today :)

Comment: @user2405469 No worries, we all need a second pair of eyes from time to time